# Under spf13-vim, how to jump to next item in the loop

Tags: python, for-loop, vim

I am new to spf13-vim configuration. I have a basic problem; for example, when I am writing a python script, if I type "for" in vim console, I could see:

```
1 for item in <`2:items`>:
2     <`0`>
```

Then I can type any variable on "item", but I couldn't figure out how to jump to the next item, "<`2:items`>". How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The direct answer to your question is: press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
2. This feature is most certainly *not* provided by spf13 itself: it is provided by a snippet-expansion plugin that comes with spf13. Maybe it's SnipMate? Maybe it's UltiSnips? Maybe another one? Who even knows? You could simply look up up the documentation of that plugin but you can't, because you don't know what plugins you have.

   Well, *you* are supposed to know what the plugins *you* add to *your* config that *you* manage *yourself* do and do not. But you don't, because you gave away that responsibility to someone else and you end up with a black box that contains and does things you have no idea about.

   And the best part is that you don't even ask for help to the author/maintainer of that crappy distribution. They lured you into installing their stuff and giving control up, they are the ones who should help their poor, misled, users.
3. If you are serious about using Vim, drop spf13 immediately and take care of *your* configuration *yourself*.

   If you don't care about doing things the right way, use another editor.

Comment: Thank you! I will follow your suggestion and start over.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to jump to the next item.